# Force child class to implement member class

Tags: c#, inheritance, virtual

First of all, I would like to say that I am mainly interested in if the following is possible, and I do not intent to actually implement it anywhere soon, and as such bad design is not relevant at this moment. I understand this is easily achieved by using a virtual function.

**Question explanation**

The following is an example of what I am trying to achieve. It is by no means correct C#.

Say I have a class `Foo` which contains an abstract class `Bar`, which then contains a function `Foobar`. Class `Foo` uses this `Foobar` function somewhere in a protected function. This is ofcourse not correct C#, as you cannot create an instance of an abstract class.

```
Class Foo
{
    protected abstract class Bar
    {
        public void Foobar();
    }

    public void RandomFunction()
    {
        Bar bar = new Bar();
        bar.Foobar();
    }
}
```

I now create a child class of `Foo`, named `FooChild`. Since `Bar` is abstract, `FooChild` is forced to override this class.

```
Class FooChild : Foo
{
    override class Bar
    {
        public void Foobar()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This is FooChild.");
        }
    }
}
```

Say there is a different part of this program, which requires an instance of class `Foo`.

```
void UseFoo(Foo myFoo)
{
    myFoo.RandomFunction();
}
```

He gets this class via some other function. However, since FooChild is a child of Foo, it can be passed to the function instead.

```
UseFoo(new FooChild());
```

The expected outcome of this program would be:

> This is FooChild.

*My question is, what the correct syntax would be for this, or instead a reasoning why this is not possible.*

Comment: It looks like you just want to make `Foo` abstract as well..

Comment: Would that force a child to override the Bar class? I did not even think of this as remotely a correct syntax.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead I just tried this, and it seems this does not work, as it does not solve the problem of `RandomFunction` trying to instance an abstract class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important to remember that [C# nested types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173120.aspx) are a static construct. So the abstract `Bar` nested in `Foo` does not have any real bearing on subclassing `Foo` - the situation would be the same if you instead declared `Bar` outside of `Foo` (other than the fact it's nested).

This is slightly confused by the fact that when you subclass `Foo` with `FooChild`, you inherit `FooChild.Bar` which is the same as `Foo.Bar` - but this is static member inheritance, therefore only really a matter of scope.

Now removing the nesting of `Bar`, your question really boils down to the line you notice is invalid C#:

```
    Bar bar = new Bar();
```

since `Bar` is abstract, *somebody* will need to subclass `Bar` in order to create something of that type. You might arrange for this to be passed in from the outside, or created directly in your subclass. Or if you want to force the subclass to also subclass `Bar` you could use an abstract factory method on `Foo`:

```
abstract class Foo
{
    public abstract Bar CreateBar();
    public void RandomFunction()
    {
        Bar bar = CreateBar();
        bar.Foobar();
    }
}
```

Notice that whether your subclass creates the derived `Bar` subclass as a nested class or at the top level is irrelevant to this design.

Comment: Thanks you very much. This is about the answer I was looking for.